# Getting TypeError at /login/: authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying to authenticate the user using Django in-built User model. Here is the view of the login page:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard')
    usern = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        userinfo = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        print('entering')
        for user_det in userinfo:
            usern=user_det.username
        print(usern)
        user = authenticate(request, username=usern, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            print('available')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password incorrect')
            return render(request, 'account/login.html') 
            
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')
```

After logging in, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError at /login/

authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

I have seen some stack overflow before and they suggested ambiguity issue with a view and auth function naming.

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you import `authenticate(...)` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using an older version of Django.

in that case, you don't need to supply the request.

```
authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

Comment: Actually, it was a missed letter issue. Also, I implemented what Yuval said. Thanks to all who replied!

Answer (score 0):

I had another function below in my views.py which was clashing with the `authenticate()` function, I thought I had changed it to `authenticated(request)` but it was the same.

My bad.